# draw a distribution graph in android

Tags: android

I want to draw a simple graph like this in android. Can it be drawn without the help of any external jar. Please give some solution.I have searched a lot but unable to get any information on this.Actually this is a bell curve, and every where i got an equation i.e the Gaussian equation, but i exactly don't know how to use it(get the X and Y coordinates from it).Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a project developed by developers to display different charts in android...

http://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/

http://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/wiki/Screenshots

**EDIT:-**

The below link will also help you.See the last answer posted by **Pied Piper**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android

Comment: yes it is possible see this...http://www.anddev.org/android-2d-3d-graphics-opengl-tutorials-f2/drawing-a-chart-in-android-t11237.html

Answer (score 0):

Just use Android built-in [2D libraries](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html). Here's [good example](http://marakana.com/tutorials/android/2d-graphics-example.html) to get you started:

Comment: actually this is a graph and it will be drawn with the help of input values

Comment: Yeah? Still you will use 2d engine to do that. Do you mean that you need the math as far as algorithm?

Comment: yes i need an algorithm to draw this graph. I found similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292824/how-to-draw-a-bell-curve-in-android  and used the given method but unable to draw, the thing is i have to get x and y co-ordinates and draw the curve.

Answer (score 0):

yas..
we can draw with the help of paint and canvas on to a BitMap.