# How to draw a bell curve in Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to draw a bell curve (Normal distribution) in Android.

I used this equation, increasing the x-axis by myself and getting the y-axis co-ordinates with respect to x-axis.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        x =  (float) ( i * 0.5);
        yy=(float) (1/Math.sqrt(0.5)*Math.sqrt(2*Math.PI));
        y=(float) (yy*Math.exp(-Math.pow(x, 2)/2*.5));
        xcord.add(x);
        ycord.add(y);
    }
```

and then drawing line by using this

```
for(i=0;i<arraysize;i++)
canvas.drawLine(xcord.get(i),ycord.get(i),xcord.get(i+1),ycord.get(i+1), paint);
```

I don't know how to get coordinates which will form a bell curve.